# How to expnad size of root partition, and using Swap Partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, swap, disk-management

My computer have 500 GB hard drive, and partition table as following

```
367 MB - Windows 8 Loader
104 GB - Windows 8
332 GB - Personal Stuff
64 GB - extended from above partition previously it was ~400 GB.
 5 GB - Ext4 for Ubuntu
 4.1 GB - Swap Partition
```

(above 2 partition, 5gb and 4.1gb were automatically created when I install Ubuntu, I choose the option "side-by-side windows 8" (or something like that) when I installed Ubuntu.

```
 55 GB - Again Personal Stuff
```

[image: Partition image]

Now I'm running with low space problem, and I want to merge the Partition 7 and Partition 5 to Partition 6, how can I do that

Answer (score 1):

**Note: When dealing with partitions, make sure that you have a complete backup in case something goes wrong.**

It is best that you do this from the Ubuntu LiveCD, since partitions have to be un-mounted.

Well first of all you need to backup your Personal Stuff from partition 5, and turn swap off.  To disable swap, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo swapoff -a
```

Once you get that done, use Gparted to delete the partitions, and clear them so you can extend partition 6.  Right click on partition 6, unmount, and then resize.  (image below is for informational purposes only).  Make sure that you leave some space for swap, and enable swap once done, by typing:

```
Sudo swapon -a
```

I hope that this answers your question.

[image]

Comment: how much space should i left for Swap

Comment: If RAM is less that 2GB, then swap=amount of RAM.  If RAM is greater that 2GB, then swap=2GB.  I personally recommend twice the size of RAM up to 4GB.