# Cannot move swap space

Tags: gparted

This has been asked here, [Why I'm seeing a lock besides the partition I'm trying to modify with gparted?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/51272/how-do-i-repartition-with-gparted), but I'm having problems.

These two partitions both have ext4 as their file system. They are both unmounted. Swap space is swapped off:[image: both]

**I want to extend sda1 with sda3. I have no data on sda3**

However, when I click resize/move on sda1 I get this:

[image: sda1]

It's as big as it can go!

It's the same story if sda3 is empty unallocated space:

[image: unallocated]

**sda1 is as big as it can be. How do I extend it into the unallocated space?**

Worth mentioning that the screen shots are from a liveCD containing GParted's iso.

I gather I need to move unallocated space next to the drive that needs to be extended. I cannot click and drag sda2 containing swap space an inch.

This liveCD shouldn't be using it but it's the best answer I've had:

[image: sda5]

I can extend the swap space no problem. What does this mean?

[image: extended swap]

Comment: How do I move them? Click and drag? That doesn't work...

Comment: I've downloaded the latest GParted and yet this isn't working. I can click and drag the sliders, but I cannot click sda2 in the bar and move it at all! Why do you think this is? Is there a shortcut I can use instead?

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/326518/how-to-expnad-size-of-root-partition-and-using-swap-partition/326542#326542

Comment: You might wish to look at [Moving Space Between Partitions](http://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=moving-space-between-partitions) for an example on how to migrate unused space when primary, extended, and logical partitions are involved.

Comment: Never thought I'd say this...but this is so much easier in Windows!

Answer (score 14):

## Step 0: Backup your data

Make sure you have up to date and good backup of all your personal files. The backup must be outside your computer. If you haven't backed up your data, **stop now** and make backup.

## Step 1: Boot from a LiveCD/DVD/USB

You have done this. I am writing it for anyone who may read this later. This is important, as you can't change a tire of a car while you are driving it.

## Step 2: Disable Swap

Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, or click on the Terminal icon of live CD desktop

```
sudo swapoff -a
```

## Step 3: Delete Swap partition

Make sure the swap partition is unmounted. Right click on the Swap partition from within Gparted, and click on **Unmount**.

Now you should be able to delete swap partition. It is the logical partition `/dev/sda5` inside the extended partition `/dev/sda2`.

## Step 4: Delete Extended Partition `/dev/sda2`

The extended partition can't be deleted until the logical partition inside it is deleted. We did that in step 3. Now we can delete `/dev/sda2`.

## Step 5: Delete `/dev/sda3`

You can delete this partition as it has no data. Then you will use most of this space to resize the `/dev/sda1`.

## Step 6: Resize sda1

Use Gparted to expand `/dev/sda1`. Leave 8GB space (or less if you want) at the end to recreate the swap partition.

## Step 7: Create a new swap partition

You can choose to create a primary partition (new `/dev/sda2`) for swap. Since you are going to have only two partitions in this drive, there is no need for an extended partition.

## Step 8: Find the new UUID of the two partitions

**Either**

In Gparted: Right click on a partition and select "Information"

**Or**

In terminal enter:

```
sudo blkid
```

And write down (or copy to a text editor) the two UUIDs for sda1 (`/` partition) and sda2 (swap).

## Step 9: Edit `/etc/fstab`

Mount the main partition, i.e.

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/mount_sda1
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/mount_sda1
```

and navigate to `/mnt/mount_sda1/etc/`  folder.

Find the file called `fstab`. Copy the new UUID in their appropriate places if needed.

If there is any lines related to the old `/dev/sda3`, you should delete that. As that partition does not exist any more.

Hope this is helpful

Comment: GParted can show the UUID, if you right click a partition and choose "Information".

Comment: and no data will be lost during this process?

Comment: @Zhenyu I cannot guarantee that no data will be lost. Always have good and multiple backups of your data outside the computer.

Comment: @mook765 I have revised the answer to take into account the extended partition.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this in my VM like this:

- Right click on the swap partition in between and select Swapoff
  [image]
- Right click on it again and select "Resize/Move"
- Drag that swap partition all the way to the right and click Resize/Move.
  [image]
- Right Click on the full partition and select "Resize/Move"
- Now you will be able to resize it and make use of the unallocated space
  [image]
- Click "Resize" and "Apply Changes" (✓ button).

Answer (score 0):

An addition to [above answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/510411/1126258), if your distro uses initramfs , you need to change swap partition UUID there too.

Change this line in the file /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume

```
RESUME=UUID=b007b23d-e1b5-40de-a8fb-dc2d89f83347
```

and then run

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```