# Can't resize VM disk, 2nd disk partition blocking first?

Tags: 18.04, partitioning, disk, disk-management

I have before me the following problem:

```
Filesystem                                                     Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1                                                       28G   26G  240M 100% /
```

So, looking to expand this disk, I do the following:

```
$ sudo parted /dev/sda
GNU Parted 3.2
Using /dev/sda
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) print                                                            
Model: ATA QEMU HARDDISK (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 50.5GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  30.1GB  30.1GB  primary   ext4            boot
 2      30.1GB  40.0GB  9934MB  extended
 5      30.1GB  34.4GB  4293MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)

(parted) resizepart                                                       
Partition number? 1                                                       
Warning: Partition /dev/sda1 is being used. Are you sure you want to continue?
Yes/No? Yes                                                               
End?  [30.1GB]? 40GB                                                      
Error: Can't have overlapping partitions.
```

I was surprised to find Number 2 and 5, and also that number 2 appears to go to 40GB and number 5 starts at the same point and only goes to 34.4GB.

Someone must have tried this before me but also failed.

Also strange: /dev/sda**2** exists but does not show up in the output of `df -h`.

I don't know what to do here. Do I need to merge sda1 and sda2 somehow? How would I even do that? What about that swap partition? Do I need to change it to start at the end of sda2? How do I do that?

Any help would be appreciated. I just want to get this system to be simple and orderly, easy to manage.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot move swap space](https://askubuntu.com/questions/510393/cannot-move-swap-space)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/dev/sda2` is an **extended** partition.  What this means is it's one large partition that within it can be placed multiple 'logical' partitions - in this case, `/dev/sda2` is an extended partition that fills the rest of your disk after the first partition `/dev/sda1`, and within `/dev/sda2` your swap partition exists as `/dev/sda5`.

To extend your `/dev/sda1` you need to do the following first:

1. Disable your swap partition.  `sudo swapoff /dev/sda5`
2. Using `gparted`, shrink `/dev/sda2` so it contains *only* `/dev/sda5` and no free space.
3. Using `gparted`, move `/dev/sda2` and `/dev/sda5` together to the end of the disk.
4. Resize (grow) your `/dev/sda1` after the previous tasks are completed.
5. Reenable your swap partition.  `sudo swapon /dev/sda5`

Alternatively, you can do the following instead, which gets you more in line with what modern Ubuntu does (which is to use **swapfiles** instead of swap *partitions*):

1. Disable your swap partition.  `sudo swapoff /dev/sda5`
2. **Delete** both partition 5 and Partition 2 via `parted`
3. Grow your `/dev/sda1` and its filesystem.
4. Use a swapfile instead of a swap partition, from within your single partition.

   ```
   sudo fallocate -l 4GiB /swapfile
   sudo mkswap /swapfile
   sudo swapon /swapfile
   ```
5. Once the swapfile is created, add this to `/etc/fstab` on the end of the line so that the swapfile is enabled automatically at boot time:

   ```
   /swapfile    swap    swap    sw    0    0
   ```

Comment: Oh dear, it's been almost a year since I checked this account.

The second option worked, but needed on more command for createing the swap file, as step 2: `sudo mkswap /swapfile`

Answer (score -2):

You can use these two commands

```
sudo growpart /dev/sda 
sudo resize2fs /dev/sda
```

Comment: Won't work because of overlapping partitions.